# Is there a workaround to modify the file and be able to print (in CMYK) the effects using the ‘difference’ blending mode in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cmyk, blend-modes

I have offen encountered this issue when working in RGB using the Difference mode under the Oppacity panel, and would want to save the artwork (attached image) for printing. When converting the file for printing to CMYK, the effects will be lost due as CMYK doesn't support it. But is there a workround or plugin to modify the effects so these coloring of graphics reflect in RGB?

[image]

Comment: Flatten transparency.

Comment: THANKS so much. This solved my problem perfectly. That was a bigblind spot of my Illustrator skill/printing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If you select the art and choose...

`Object > Flatten Transparency`, then move the slider all the way to the right (vector) you can "bake in" the blending.

What this does is expand the objects and merges them to maintain appearance over construction. The resulting appearance will simply be filled with color to match the appearance but there will be no blending modes. This also **breaks apart the artwork**. This is a **destructive** feature. If you need construction to remain easily edited, then flatten transparency on a *duplicate* of the art and retain the original in case changes are necessary in the future.

Other than this you can *manually* determine the colors you want, then split objects, remove blending modes, and then manually assign colors to the areas.

Flatten Transparency will work a great of the time, but it's not a be-all-end-all. There are times where one needs to rethink construction *without* any blending modes.

Comment: Explained crystal clear. Thank you so much again.